# How to iterate list of objects by object field with Google Guava lexicographical?

Tags: java, list, sorting, object, guava

Something like:

```
Ordering<Iterable<ImportXmlRecord>> comparator =
                Ordering.natural().lexicographical().onResultOf();
```

But sort by ImportXmlRecord field?

Answer (score 3):

Not quite:

```
Ordering<Iterable<ImportXmlRecord>> comparator = Ordering.natural()
  .onResultOf(new Function<ImportXmlRecord, Whatever>() {
    public Whatever apply(ImportXmlRecord x) { return x.getWhatever(); }
  }.lexicographical();
```